# Display data on client side as per user's selection

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I am fairly new to this side of development, so please bear with me.

I am trying to build a website where user will select their options from drop down and would be able to see the results. To achieve this, I have created a node js app and I am querying a sqlite database.

I am not sure, how to display the data on the client side as per users selection. Can any body show me an example how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways we can do this. What will result in a better user experience is to use AJAX to ask the server for some data, get that data on the client, and then modify the DOM to show this data. The workflow is as follows:

1. User chooses option
2. We make an AJAX request to the server depending on that option
3. We get a response from the server
4. We modify the DOM to reflect this new data

To get this to work you'll need to:

- register an event handler for the `select` element's onchange event.
- make an AJAX request to your node.js server.
- setup an endpoint on your node.js server that listens for these requests.
- implement your database lookup in this endpoint and return the response (typically in JSON).
- back on the client (ie browser), when your AJAX request resolves, you will need to update a part of the DOM to show this data. You can do this using client-side templating libraries like Handlebars OR you can use the native API (here's a good article: http://blog.garstasio.com/you-dont-need-jquery/dom-manipulation/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Calvin Belden